# How to achieve an Angular 6+ Bootstrap tabset right-aligned tab?

Tags: css, angular, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angular 6 and Bootstrap (and still learning Angular). I have a tabset with multiple tabs and the last tab needs to be right aligned.

In vanilla Bootstrap I can just add the class `ml-auto` to the last tab to get it to align to the right. This class just boils down to `margin-left: auto !important;` so I should theoretically be able to style this if I can pin down the relevant element.

```
<li class="nav-item ml-auto">
    <a class="nav-link" role="tab">My Right Tab</a>
</li>
```

However the Angular code is more opaque:

```
<ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>My Right Tab</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ...
    </ng-template>
 </ngb-tab>
```

And builds out all the relevant Bootstrapified HTML when it compiles.

The `<ngb-tab>` bit becomes the `<a>` tag in the HTML, not the `<li>`, so I can't apply an id or class to that from which to hook the relevant style (and there is no parent selector in CSS).

Complicating this is an additional nested tabset with different styling in the tab content of the various tabs. I've isolated that with a class on a div wrapping the tabset. However I can't do the same thing with the outside tabset. So I can set the left margin on the tab by using `:last-of-type` on `.nav-item` and then override it in the nested tabset, but this feels like a lot of really unclear acrobatics to achieve something that should be super simple.

Is there an easier, clearer, more angular way to do this? Is there a way to apply a bootstrap class? Can I just write the bootstrap html in the tabset (I've not tried this since it seems un-angular)?